# Jquery Shopping Cart Drag & Drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, shopping-cart

I found this website, with great shopping cart :
http://superdit.com/2011/04/02/drag-drop-shopping-cart-using-jquery/comment-page-1/#comment-27491

Instead of having 1 shopping cart, i'd like to have 2.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JQuery Drag & Drop Cart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Arial, "Free Sans";
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #main {
        background: #0099cc;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 2px 0 4px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #main a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    #main a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #item_container {
        width: 610px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .item {
        background: #fff;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        cursor: move;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    .title, .price {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: move;
    }
    .title {
        color: #333;
    }
    .price {
        color: #0099cc;
        margin-top: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
    }
    .icart, .icart label {
        cursor: e-resize;
    }
    .divrm {
        text-align: right;
    }
    .remove {
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        position: relative;
        top: -7px;
    }
    .remove:hover {
        color: #999;
    }
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
    #cart_container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 495px;
    }
    #cart_title span {
        border: 8px solid #666;
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        background: #333;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
        border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
    }
    #cart_toolbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 8px solid #666;
        height: 190px;
        z-index: -2;
        width: 483px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
        border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    #cart_items {
        height: 190px;
        width: 483px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 0 0 2px;
        z-index: 0;
        cursor: e-resize;
        border-width: 0 2px;
    }
    .back {
        background: #e9e9e9;
    }
    #navigate {
        width: 463px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 8px solid #666;
        border-top-width: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
        border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        background: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #nav_left {
        float: left;
    }
    #nav_left a {
        padding: 4px 8px;
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#0099cc;
    }
    #nav_left a:hover {
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #nav_right {
        float: right;
    }
    .sptext {
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        margin-left: 8px;            
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        color: #666;
    }
    .count {
        color: #0099cc;
    }
    .drop-active {
        background: #ffff99;
    }
    .drop-hover {
        background: #ffff66;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var total_items = 0;
var total_price = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".item").draggable({
        revert: true            
    });
    $("#cart_items").draggable({
        axis: "x"
    });

    $("div[id^='cart_items']").droppable({
        accept: ".item",
        activeClass: "drop-active",
        hoverClass: "drop-hover",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var item = ui.draggable.html();
            var itemid = ui.draggable.attr("id");
            var html = '<div class="item icart">';
            html = html + '<div class="divrm">';
            html = html + '<a onclick="remove(this)" class="remove '+itemid+'">&times;</a>';
            html = html + '<div/>'+item+'</div>';
            $(this).append(html);

            // update total items
            total_items++;
            $("#citem").html(total_items);

            // update total price
            var price = parseInt(ui.draggable.find(".price").html().replace("$ ", ""));
            total_price = total_price + price;
            $("#cprice").html("$ " + total_price);

            // expand cart items
            if (total_items > 4) {
               $(this).animate({width: "+=120"}, 'slow');
            }
        }
    });


    $("#btn_next").click(function() {
        $("#cart_items").animate({left: "-=100"}, 100);
        return false;
    });
    $("#btn_prev").click(function() {
        $("#cart_items").animate({left: "+=100"}, 100);
        return false;
    });
    $("#btn_clear").click(function() {
        $("#cart_items").fadeOut("2000", function() {
           $(this).html("").fadeIn("fast").css({left: 0});
        });
        $("#citem").html("0");
        $("#cprice").html("$ 0");
        total_items = 0;
        total_price = 0;
        return false;
    });
});
function remove(el) {
    $(el).hide();
    $(el).parent().parent().effect("highlight", {color: "#ff0000"}, 1000);
    $(el).parent().parent().fadeOut('1000');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).parent().parent().remove();
        // collapse cart items
        if (total_items > 3) {
            $("#cart_items").animate({width: "-=120"}, 'slow');
        }
    }, 1100);

    // update total item
    total_items--;
    $("#citem").html(total_items);

    // update totl price
    var price = parseInt($(el).parent().parent().find(".price").html().replace("$ ", ""));
    total_price = total_price - price;
    $("#cprice").html("$ " + total_price);
}
</script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="item_container">
      <div class="item" id="i1">
          <img src="img/1.jpg"/>
          <label class="title">T-Shirt 1</label>
          <label class="price">$ 20</label>
      </div>

      <div class="item" id="i2">
          <img src="img/2.jpg"/>
          <label class="title">T-Shirt 2</label>
          <label class="price">$ 24</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="i3">
          <img src="img/3.jpg"/>
          <label class="title">T-Shirt 3</label>

          <label class="price">$ 18</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="i4">
          <img src="img/4.jpg"/>
          <label class="title">T-Shirt 4</label>
          <label class="price">$ 30</label>
      </div>

      <div class="item" id="i5">
          <img src="img/5.jpg"/>
          <label class="title">T-Shirt 5</label>
          <label class="price">$ 28</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="i6">
          <img src="img/6.jpg"/>
          <label class="title">T-Shirt 6</label>

          <label class="price">$ 26</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="i7">
          <img src="img/7.jpg"/>
          <label class="title">T-Shirt 7</label>
          <label class="price">$ 35</label>
      </div>

      <div class="item" id="i8">
          <img src="img/8.jpg"/>
          <label class="title">T-Shirt 8</label>
          <label class="price">$ 33</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="i9">
          <img src="img/9.jpg"/>
          <label class="title">T-Shirt 1</label>

          <label class="price">$ 12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="i10">
          <img src="img/10.jpg"/>
          <label class="title">T-Shirt 10</label>
          <label class="price">$ 22</label>
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="cart_container">
      <div id="cart_title">
          <span>Shopping Cart</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="cart_toolbar">

          <div id="cart_items1" class="back"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="navigate">
          <div id="nav_left">
              <a href="" id="btn_prev"><</a>
              <a href="" id="btn_next">></a>
              <a href="" id="btn_clear">Clear Cart</a>

          </div>
          <div id="nav_right">
              <span class="sptext">
                  <label>Items </label><label class="count" id="citem">0</label>
              </span>
              <span class="sptext">
                  <label>Price </label><label class="count" id="cprice">$ 0</label>

              </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="cart_container">
      <div id="cart_title">
          <span>Shopping Cart</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="cart_toolbar">

          <div id="cart_items2" class="back"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="navigate">
          <div id="nav_left">
              <a href="" id="btn_prev"><</a>
              <a href="" id="btn_next">></a>
              <a href="" id="btn_clear">Clear Cart</a>

          </div>
          <div id="nav_right">
              <span class="sptext">
                  <label>Items </label><label class="count" id="citem">0</label>
              </span>
              <span class="sptext">
                  <label>Price </label><label class="count" id="cprice">$ 0</label>

              </span>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My problem is, my cart don't change color, and are not dropable
Could you help please

Answer (score 0):

In your  tags change the of div from cart_items1 and cart_items2 to cart_items for both and it will work
i.e.

```
<div id="cart_container">
      <div id="cart_title">
          <span>Shopping Cart</span>
          <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="cart_toolbar">

          <div id="cart_items" class="back"></div>
.....
```